# adding image working in localhost but not in online

Tags: .net

I am working in a form that will simply add images. The code working properly in localhost but not in online. please help

underneath is the code I have tried:-

Protected Sub btnsaveImg_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnsaveImg.Click
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(Dal.conMain)
        Try
            'Dim x As String = ""

```
        Dim g As Guid
        g = Guid.NewGuid
        Dim title As String = txtTitle.Text
        'Dim posted_on As Date = Date.Parse(txtpostOn.Text)
        Dim desc As String = txtDecs.Text
        If fileuploadthumb.FileName <> "" Then
            Dim imgthumb As String = fileuploadthumb.PostedFile.FileName
            Dim str As String() = imgthumb.Split(".")
            Dim strex As String = str(1)
            Dim imagenm As String = "~/uploads/" + g.ToString() + "." + strex
            Dim path As String = Server.MapPath(imagenm)
            fileuploadthumb.SaveAs(path)
        End If
        If fileuploadimg.FileName <> "" Then
            Dim img As String = fileuploadimg.PostedFile.FileName
            Dim str2 As String() = img.Split(".")
            Dim strex2 As String = str2(1)
            Dim imgnm As String = "~/uploads/" + g.ToString() + "." + strex2
            Dim path1 As String = Server.MapPath(imgnm)
            fileuploadimg.SaveAs(path1)
        End If
        Dim obj As New clsAddImageGallery


        obj.imgTitle = txtTitle.Text
        obj.imgDesc = txtDecs.Text
        Dim imgth1 As String = fileuploadimg.PostedFile.FileName
        Dim str1 As String() = imgth1.Split(".")
        Dim strex1 As String = str1(1)
        obj.img = "~/uploads/" + g.ToString() + "." + strex1
        Dim imgth3 As String = fileuploadthumb.PostedFile.FileName
        Dim str3 As String() = imgth1.Split(".")
        Dim strex3 As String = str3(1)
        obj.imgTh = "~/uploads/" + g.ToString() + "." + strex3
        'obj.unqid = 0
        Dim x As New Int64
        'Dim trns As SqlTransaction

        'con.Open()
        'trns = con.BeginTransaction()
        x = obj.fn_sv_AddImageGallery(con)
        If x > 0 Then
            'trns.Commit()
            'con.Close()
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Image Added...!!')</script>")
            lblunqid.Text = x
            sbloadgrd()

        Else
            'trns.Rollback()
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Error saving data..!!')</script>")
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception

        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  Or does the image just not show?  Does `~/uploads/` exist on your server?  Does the IIS app pool have permissions to write to it?  Does the file get copied to it?

Comment: yes i get an error.Server                                                                     Error in '/' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: Turn custom errors off by modifying the web.config file so you can identify the error :)